# Dynamic web user control problem when browser's back button is clicked

Tags: asp.net, browser, user-controls, back-button

I have an .aspx page in which I dynamically add web controls to a panel.
The problem is when I hit the browser's back buton, it's displayed a version of the page that no longer exists on the server-side, because the controls are dynamically added.
Let's say my aspx dynamically adds Control1. From there, I click a button that loads Control2.
At this moment, if I press the browser's back button, it will display the page with Control1, but Control1 no longer exists on the server-side, so if I interact with it, some erractic behaviour will occur. Any ideas on this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What kind of ideas are you looking for? Do you want someone to explain why this is happening? Do you need a solution of some sort?

Comment: @Oded: Well, if you can explain me how can I avoid this situation, it will be awesome :)

Comment: You need to add no caching directives on the page, so the browser does not cache it and has to get it from the server again.

Comment: @Oded: Thak you for your input, but it seems it's not related to browser caching.

Comment: How do you know? Clicking the back button will cause the cached version on the browser to load.

Comment: @Oded: I've already added no caching directives. The problem seems to be related with the browser and web server being in different states.
As I showed in my example, after clicking the back button, only the browser knows Control1. Server only knows Control2.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the client side to not cache pages - stick this in your page load:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheing.NoCache)
```

(Think the syntax might be slightly off, but you should be able to figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with removing temporary files and restarting browser. Your page might be cached in browser.

Comment: Thank for you input, but I think it's not related to browser caching.